# How to Refine my code

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any other way on how to refine my code?

```
Sub save_item(ByVal strtype As String, ByVal strgendes As String, ByVal strquantity As String, ByVal strfund As String, ByVal strebudget As String, _
                  ByVal strtotaltenpercent As String, ByVal strjan As String, ByVal strfeb As String, ByVal strmarch As String, _
                  ByVal strapril As String, ByVal strmay As String, ByVal strjune As String, ByVal strjuly As String, _
                  ByVal straug As String, ByVal strsept As String, ByVal stroct As String, ByVal strnov As String, ByVal strdec As String, _
                  ByVal strq1 As String, ByVal strq2 As String, ByVal strq3 As String, ByVal strq4 As String, ByVal strtotal_item As String,
_
                  ByVal strtotalprice As String, ByVal strdate As String, ByVal stryear As String)

    Dim saveall As New tblPPMP With {.Type = strtype, _
                                     .GenDes = strgendes, _
                                     .Quantity = strquantity, _
                                     .Fund = strfund, _
                                     .Ebudget = strebudget, _
                                     .Total_tenpercent = strtotaltenpercent, _
                                     .Jan = strjan, _
                                     .Feb = strfeb, _
                                     .March = strmarch, _
                                     .April = strapril, _
                                     .May = strmay, _
                                     .June = strjune, _
                                     .Jul = strjuly, _
                                     .Aug = straug, _
                                     .Sept = strsept, _
                                     .Oct = stroct, _
                                     .Nov = strnov, _
                                     .Dec = strdec, _
                                     .Q1 = strq1, _
                                     .Q2 = strq2, _
                                     .Q3 = strq3, _
                                     .Q4 = strq4, _
                                     .Total_Item = strtotal_item, _
                                     .Total_Price = strtotalprice, _
                                     .dr_date = strdate, _
                                     .dr_year = stryear}

    dbcon.tblPPMPs.InsertOnSubmit(saveall)
    MsgBox("Save Successfully")
    Try
        dbcon.SubmitChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching and then throwing a new Exception seems pointless. Remove that.

Comment: sir? where?.. is there any other way to shorten this code?